# OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError - read finished A: decryption failed or bad record mac

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ssl, encryption, rest-client

I am using `RestClient` to access an external `API` using a certificate available.
I have useed it like this,

```
require 'rest-client'

p12 = OpenSSL::PKCS12.new(File.read('/root/cert.p12'), 'password')

RestClient::Request.execute(method: :post, url: "https://myurl.com", ssl_client_cert: p12.certificate, ssl_cert_key: p12.key, payload: { data: "" }, verify_ssl: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE)
```

On doing the above steps, I get :

> OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read finished A: decryption failed or bad record mac

Can someone help me out in this?

Comment: Shouldn't this `https:myurl.com` be `https://myurl.com` ?

Comment: Thanks Edited :-)

Comment: I got the answer from a different question. Please refer this link - http://stackoverflow.com/a/42613785/4028429